# Not able to access Windows after installing Ubuntu

Tags: secure-boot

After installing Ubuntu I saw this MOK management options and I've selected to continue booting.

[image]

Then the Windows asked me for bitlocker key and now I'm not able to log in to Windows.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try this code:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

2. Open grub customizer.
3. Refresh the list and arrange the list of order.
4. Save and reboot the system.

Answer (score 0):

If your Windows had a Microsoft account associated with it, you may find the bitlocker key by [logging in to your account](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=237614).